# Create folder with OneDrive for Android

Tags: java, android, onedrive

I am currently implementing file storage using OneDrive with the [Android SDK](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android/) and cannot find a method to create a folder with a given name inside another folder. How can I do this?

Comment: maybe you should read this? https://dev.onedrive.com/items/create.htm

Comment: how can I translate this into the Java/Android API?

Comment: using an API client like Volley or Retrofit, https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html

Comment: that's what I want to avoid by using an API in the target language. The OneDrive SDK handles token management nicely, not sure if I want to try to get the token out of it for one call which should be doable through the API as well.